# How to shrink table automatically to device width and font to reduce automatically like zoom out

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, width

I have table like this into my webpage,
where x are single digit[numeric] data.

When I open webpage into mobile browser its width overflows to the screen.

Other element like header footer and other divs always fits to the screen but table exceeds to the screen width limit.

I want that only table should zoom out to fit the screen means all font size should reduced accordingly.

Could anybody help me please?

My table css is:-

```
table{border-spacing:5px;border-collapse:collapse}th,td{padding:5px}
```

My table html is:-

```
<table><tr>
<th>
<p align="center">22/02/16<br />to<br />27/02/16</p>
</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font color="red" size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font color="red" size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<p>          </font></tr>
<tr>
<th>
<p align="center">29/02/16<br />to<br />05/03/16</p>
</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font color="red" size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font color="red" size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<p> </font></tr>
<tr>
<th>
<p align="center">07/03/16<br />to<br />12/03/16</p>
</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<p>          </font></tr>
<tr>
<th>
<p align="center">14/03/16<br />to<br />14/03/16</p>
</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<th><font size="6">xx</font></th>
<th>x<br />x<br />x</th>
<p>          </font></tr></table>
```

If I zoom out the page in mobile browser it looks like this:

[image]

but I want result like this without zooming out

[image]

Comment: can tou please create a snippet with relevant code (including css)?

Comment: i dont know how to create snippet.

Comment: It's the time for you to learn [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). This is what exactly you're looking for, The [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).